# PHP variable not getting resolved in html page

Tags: php

I have a.php  where I do a DB query and assign that to list  like this..

```
list($A,$B)=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT A,B FROM configs WHERE idone=$v AND id='$inputid' LIMIT 1"));

            $p=array();
            $p=@explode(';,',base64_decode($A));
            $bg=$p[0];
            $A='';

            $i=0;
            foreach($p as $X){
                if(++$i>1) $A.='\''.str_replace(':-',':',$X).'\',';
            }

require'templates/inner_play.htm';
```

Now in inner_play.htm , I am using $A and $B from then above list like this..

```
 'image': '<?php echo $A?>',
 'URL' : '<?php echo $B ?>'
```

I can get the values for $A  but $B does not resolve.?
am i missing anything.?

**Note:
    I can;t change the inner_play.htm  to php as its part of bigger template system  and I do get the value for $A in  the same Htm but for some reason I am not getting $B.**

Comment: [The mysql_* functions are **DEPRECATED**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), and you really should use the much-improved [mysqli_* functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or a [PHP Data Object interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: sure , thanks for the suggestion.this is a one of work for someone else's script.The sql part work but the $B  never passes the value to inner.play.htm

Answer (score 2):

Rename `inner_play.htm` to `inner_play.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that .html files can not execute PHP functions sucha as `echo`.

You should rename your inner_play.htm to inner_play.php if you want to use any PHP inside.

Comment: I don;t think that's true .. as I am getting the data for $A in the same htm . its the $B which doesn't get resolved in htm file

Answer (score 0):

change the extention to .php or .phtml 
simple htm extension can't understand the php code
Valid extension for php code are php and phtml

Answer (score 0):

Or you can setup server to run html as php:

Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's already setup. that's how i get the value for $A in htm file, its the $B which is causing problem

Comment: maybe $B just contains NULL or False. in this case you'll not see it. do var_dump($B).